# How can I delete rows from excel 2010 Programatically

Tags: excel, vb6

I have an .xls file. I'm going through the file line by line and deleting lines I don't need. For some reason after I find the line I want to delete, I can't delete it. This should be simple but I haven't been able to get it to work for me.

I've tried

- Range("1:2").Cut  (just as an example)
- 'objWS.Rows(iCtr) = ""
- List item
- List item
- .Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row.Delete
- List item
- theDelRange.EntireRow.Delete

Thinking that the file might be blocked (which apparently is not the same as being Protected) I've tried the following:

- objExcel.ActiveSheet.protected = False
- Set .Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit = True (with
  protected set as true)

All of these run  without  errors, they just don't delete any lines in the .xls file.

Here's my code snippet

```
theProgramFilesPath = GetProgramFilesPath
Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set objWS = objWB.Worksheets(1)

objExcel.Workbooks.Open theVendorPricesFilePath
objExcel.ActiveSheet.protected = False
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Calculation = False

With objExcel 
.Application.ScreenUpdating = False     
    Set .Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit = True        
    LineCnt = .Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ColCnt = .Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For iCtr = LineCnt To 1 Step -1
        tempTxt = .Cells(iCtr, 9).Value
        If Val(tempTxt) = 0 Then   (Here's where I need to delete the row)
            'theDelRange = .Range(.Cells(iCtr, 1), .Cells(iCtr, 10))        '.EntireRow.Delete)
            'theDelRange.EntireRow.Delete
            '.Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row.Delete
            'objWS.Rows(iCtr) = ""
            'Range("1:2").Cut
        End If            
    Next
.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Such a simple thing...sigh. Any help really appreciated.

Comment: `EntireRow.Delete` works, so something else is going on. BTW - `objExcel.Application` is redundant - `objExcel` is already a reference to the Application object, so that's equivalent to `Application.Application`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that you are not referencing to the worksheet object that contains the data you'll check and delete target rows.

In your code snippets, you start with `with objExcel` which is an Excel instance, then you did not reference to  `Workbook` and then to which `worksheets("index")` (which exists in the first lines in your code `objWS`.)

```
    With objExcel 
    .Application.ScreenUpdating = False     
    Set .Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit = True        
    LineCnt = .Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ColCnt = .Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For iCtr = LineCnt To 1 Step -1
        tempTxt = .Cells(iCtr, 9).Value
        If Val(tempTxt) = 0 Then   (Here's where I need to delete the row)
            'theDelRange = .Range(.Cells(iCtr, 1), .Cells(iCtr, 10))        '.EntireRow.Delete)
            'theDelRange.EntireRow.Delete
            '.Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row.Delete
            'objWS.Rows(iCtr) = ""
            'Range("1:2").Cut
        End If            
    Next
.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Thus, you should try using that object as follows :

```
For iCtr = LineCnt To 1 Step -1
        with objWS
               tempTxt = .Cells(iCtr, 9).Value
               If Val(tempTxt) = 0 Then   (Here's where I need to delete the row)
                theDelRange = .Range(.Cells(iCtr, 1), .Cells(iCtr, 10)) 'I suppose that here
               ' you have declared theDelRange as a Range object ;)      
                theDelRange.EntireRow.Delete

                End If
        End With


    Next
```